# IMAP URL fetch body structure

Tags: url, imap

I need to fetch mailbox information using an IMAP URL request. These are detailed in [RFC5092](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5092.pdf). I have succeeded in fetching parts of the body with URLs such as

```
imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX/;UID=4/;SECTION=1
```

which is equivalent to the command

```
UID FETCH 4 BODY.PEEK[1]
```

Is there a way, using only a URL to fetch the bodystructure (`UID FETCH 4 BODYSTRUCTURE`) of a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any such way. 5092 only provides access to some IMAP entities, and the bodystructure is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you. I found another solution using cURL.